# Capture text between ','

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a line in text containing commas. I want to capture data bewteen commas.

```
line = "",,,,,,,,,ce: appears to assume ,that\n
```

I was using regex capture pattern = `(""),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)\\n`

Output is:

```
Output 1
1.  ""
2.  ,
3.  Empty
4.  Empty
5.  Empty
6.  Empty
7.  Empty
8.  Empty
9.  ce: appears to assume
10. that
```

I wanted to ahve output as:

```
Output 2
1.  ""
2.  Empty
3.  Empty
4.  Empty
5.  Empty
6.  Empty
7.  Empty
8.  Empty
9.  Empty
10. ce: appears to assume, that
```

Basically I am looking for some sort of  generic greedy method which ignores comma ',' between text

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use regex? Simply split on (nine) commas. `line.split(',', 9)`

Comment: Wait, you want the last comma to be treated differently than the rest?  Also, if you remove the last `,(.*)` you should get the output that you want...

Comment: Could you clarify the precise criteria? What do you mean by "ignores comma between text"? What else would it be between?

Comment: @AdamSmith: I wanted to use regex to have a generic solution, because comma could appear any where in the text between 2 commas. But yes the input structure is fixed. I will check how the split behaves.

Comment: But we are not talking about CSV files are we?

Comment: @tanzil "comma could appear any where in the text between 2 commas" this makes your file _actually_ impossible to parse without knowing more about your data structure. If you need to include the separator in your data, it needs to be escaped or quoted.

Comment: @AdamSmith: You are right. To be precise e.g. there could be any text including comma) after 3rd and last separator.

Comment: @tanzil That's still too much to guess about. That data structure can create ambiguous data

Comment: @user3469811: It a csv file generated by converting a pdf using tabula.py

Comment: @tanzil then it should be quoting strings. If not: fix that code!

Comment: @tanzil see this link for an example of ambiguous data from this data structure https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0110abe2486551dd7952319d0d96b304

Comment: @tanzil that is an important information, could you update your question, so that everyone knows that we are talking about importing a csv file to python, generated by tabula.py

Comment: @user3469811 while I agree it's useful, the problem is that the separator `,` is not just separating entries, but is also in the data itself, so the problem will then start as "I am trying to read a csv" but again return to "How do I parse the individual lines properly?"

Comment: @C.Nivs agree. but one could also make the suggestion, to check wether it is possible to redefine the separator `,` to `;` in tabula.py. And then evaluate with python's csv module...

Comment: @user3469811 absolutely, OP could even specify `output_format='tsv'` and that could get around the issue as well

Answer (score 2):

Regex seems like the wrong solution here. If you know how many matches you're going to have (you're prescribed 10) then you know how many commas you expect. Use `str.split`

```
>>> line.split(',', 9)
['""', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ce: appears to assume ,that\n']
```

Comment: Note that if you have control of the input, you should _absolutely_ change this into something more standard. Even if the "more standard" is a quoted csv. The program shouldn't have to guess that only 9 commas define your data structure, and any additional commas are part of the data itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `itertools.groupby` here to filter on length:

```py
import itertools

someline = '"",,,,,,,,ce: appears to assume ,that\n'

# Group by length greater than 0
res = [(i, ','.join(x)) for i,x in itertools.groupby(someline.split(','), key=lambda x: len(x)>0)]

# [(True, '""'), (False, ',,,,,,'), (True, 'ce: appears to assume ,that\n')]

# Then you can just gather your results
results = []
for i, x in res:
    if i is True:
        results.append(x)
    else:
        results.extend(x.split(','))

results
# ['""', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ce: appears to assume ,that\n']
```

This avoids you having to check for a certain number of commas if that isn't a fixed value per line.

### Different Format

However, I think the real issue is that commas are not just the delimiters, but are also elements in the data, which makes this problem a bit ambiguous. Per the [docs](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py), it looks like you may be able to specify a different output format such as `.tsv`, which would separate by `\t` and avoid the problem altogether:

```py
tabula.convert_into("test.pdf", "output.tsv", output_format="tsv", pages='all')
```

Then your lines would look like:

```py
someline = '""\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tce: appears to assume ,that\n'

# Much easier to handle
someline.split('\t')

# ['""', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ce: appears to assume ,that\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you need all emptys. May this is what you are looking for

```
separados = line.split(',,')

for i in range(len(separados)):
    try:  #you can add more custom filters here
        if separados[i][0] == ',': separados[i] = separados[i][1:]
    except: pass
    try:
        if separados[i][-1] == ',': separados[i] = separados[i][:-1]
    except: pass
```

this is what you get

```
'""'
''
''
''
'ce: appears to assume ,that\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `.*` is matching too many characters, including commas.  You should create groups that match all characters **except** for commas, so something like

```
^(""),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$
```

The last one can match commas so that it will be able to match the commas in `ce: appears to assume ,that`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

reg = re.compile('^(""),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$')

match = reg.match('"",,,,,,,,,ce: appears to assume ,that\n')

for i in range(1,11):
    print('{:>2s}.  {}'.format(str(i),"Empty" if len(match.group(i))==0 else match.group(i)))
```

Gives the desired output

````
 1.  ""
 2.  Empty
 3.  Empty
 4.  Empty
 5.  Empty
 6.  Empty
 7.  Empty
 8.  Empty
 9.  Empty
10.  ce: appears to assume ,that```
````